# How to filter a 2D array based on the value of the inner array

Tags: javascript

I have a 2D array that I need to filter based on data of the Inner array

I have tried mapping then filtering the data of the inner array - but then I lose the data from the first array.

I have written a filter function below but it does not work properly- look at filteredData variable

```
var data = 
[
  {
    "batch_id": "1",
    "data": [
      {

        "identifier": "aa",
        "type": "video"
      },
      {

        "identifier": "ab",
        "type": "image"
      }
    ],
    "internal_batch_id": 72
  },
  {
    "batch_id": "2",
    "data": [
      {

        "identifier": "a",
        "type": "image"
      },
      {

        "identifier": "b",
        "type": "image"
      }
    ],
    "internal_batch_id": 72
  }
]

var type = 'video'

   var  filteredData =
      data.map((item, i) => {
        return item.data.filter((item1, idx) => {
          return item1.type.toUpperCase() === type.toUpperCase()
        })
      })
```

What I want to happen is that only the items where type === 'video' are shown.  So data would become

```
{
    "batch_id": "1",
    "data": [
      {

        "identifier": "aa",
        "type": "video"
      }

    ],
    "internal_batch_id": 72
  }
```

Comment: Yes look at my filter function

Comment: * a 2D array is an array of arrays. This is an array of objects.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what your expected out put is supposed to be. Either, you are looking to use map with filter:

> Filter the nested data prop by each type property

```js
var data = [
  {
    batch_id: '1',
    data: [{ identifier: 'aa', type: 'video' }, { identifier: 'ab', type: 'image' }],
    internal_batch_id: 72
  },
  {
    batch_id: '2',
    data: [{ identifier: 'a', type: 'image' }, { identifier: 'b', type: 'image' }],
    internal_batch_id: 72
  }
]

console.log(data.map(o => ({...o, data:o.data.filter(v => v.type === 'video')})))
```

Or you are looking to use filter with some:

> Filter entire data object to object where it has a type with 'video'

```js
var data = [
  {
    batch_id: '1',
    data: [{ identifier: 'aa', type: 'video' }, { identifier: 'ab', type: 'image' }],
    internal_batch_id: 72
  },
  {
    batch_id: '2',
    data: [{ identifier: 'a', type: 'image' }, { identifier: 'b', type: 'image' }],
    internal_batch_id: 72
  }
]

console.log(data.filter(o => o.data.some(v => v.type === 'video')))
```

Or, both:

> Filter both the entire data object, and filter the nested data.

```js
var data = [
  {
    batch_id: '1',
    data: [{ identifier: 'aa', type: 'video' }, { identifier: 'ab', type: 'image' }],
    internal_batch_id: 72
  },
  {
    batch_id: '2',
    data: [{ identifier: 'a', type: 'image' }, { identifier: 'b', type: 'image' }],
    internal_batch_id: 72
  }
]

console.log(
  data.reduce((a, o) => {
    const f = o.data.filter(v => v.type === 'video')
    return (f.length && a.push({ ...o, data: f }), a)
  }, [])
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to perform 2 operations,

- Filter parent list with all objects that has at least 1 `video` element
- Update above objects to only have `video` objects inside them.

For this you can use `.reduce` + `.filter`

- `.reduce` to create new object and create array
- `.filter` to get only filtered items in it.

```js
var data = [{ "batch_id": "1", "data": [{ "identifier": "aa", "type": "video" }, { "identifier": "ab", "type": "image" } ], "internal_batch_id": 72  }, { "batch_id": "2", "data": [{ "identifier": "a", "type": "image" }, { "identifier": "b", "type": "image" } ], "internal_batch_id": 72 }]

var type = 'video'

var filteredData = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  const innerObj = obj.data.filter((typeObj) => typeObj.type === type);
  if(innerObj.length !== 0) {
    acc.push( { ...obj, data: innerObj} );
  }
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(filteredData)
```

Comment: @downvoter, please comment if my answer is incorrect/ not required.

Comment: Question: any reason for using reduce + filter + push over map + filter + filter? I’m just curious. Readability and/or performance wise? ```data.map(item => ({...item, data: item.data.filter(inner => inner.type==="video")})).filter(item => item.data.length)
```

Comment: One obvious observationis an extra loop. Not considering inner data length, my case has `O(n)` and your solution will have `O(2n)`. But the performance difference would not be that great so you can use either case. Personally I do not like `.map + .filter`. Hence I use `.reduce`